# Socket Error ******* - Unable to find the socket transport "http"

Tags: php, sockets

When I try to lookup the domain registrar detail I received the error "Socket Error ******* - Unable to find the socket transport "http"- did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?"

```
public function whoislookup($domain){
$domain = trim($domain); //remove space from start and end of domain
if(substr(strtolower($domain), 0, 7) == "http://") $domain = substr($domain, 7); // remove http:// if included
if(substr(strtolower($domain), 0, 4) == "www.") $domain = substr($domain, 4);//remove www from domain
if(preg_match("/^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/",$domain))
    return $this->queryWhois("whois.lacnic.net",$domain);
elseif(preg_match("/^([-a-z0-9]{2,100})\.([a-z\.]{2,8})$/i",$domain))
{
    $domain_parts = explode(".", $domain);
    $tld = strtolower(array_pop($domain_parts));
    $server = $this->WHOIS_SERVERS[$tld][0];
    if(!$server) {
        return "Error: No appropriate Whois server found for $domain domain!";
    }
    $res=$this->queryWhois($server,$domain);
        while(preg_match_all("/Whois Server: (.*)/", $res, $matches))
        {
            $server=array_pop($matches[1]);
            $res=$this->queryWhois($server,$domain);
        }
    return $res;
}
else
return "Invalid Input";}

private function queryWhois($server,$domain)
{
    $fp = @fsockopen($server, 43, $errno, $errstr, 20) or die("Socket Error " . $errno . " - " . $errstr);
    if($server=="whois.verisign-grs.com")
        $domain="=".$domain;
        fputs($fp, $domain . "\r\n");
        $out = "";
        while(!feof($fp)){
            $out .= fgets($fp);
        }
    fclose($fp);
    return $out;
}
```

I am getting the domain name from the different function. Use that domain name in this function and search the whois database for getting the information of the domain registration.

Answer (score 0):

Just now I found that the lookup is not working only to "ES" and that needs an IP without blacklisted. [Limitations mentioned here](https://sede.red.gob.es/procedimientos/solicitud-de-acceso-servicio-de-whois-por-el-puerto-43/%22Limitations%20mentioned%20here%22)

Answer (score 0):

How to speed up the data transferring using socket methodology for the above code.

Thanks,
Vijay